# Mask phone number in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a script that masks any phone/10 digits numbers to `###-###-####` while typing a subject line. **The subject line has other text than the phone number.**

```
$("#subject").on('keyup', function phoneNumberC() {
        var phoneNumberRegex = /\d{10}/g;
        var questionText = document.getElementById('subject').value;
        var phoneNumberDetected = questionText.match(phoneNumberRegex);

            if (phoneNumberDetected != null){
                formattedPhone = questionText.replace(phoneNumberDetected, "###-###-####");
            }
});
```

It's not working. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a link to the CodePen for it: **https://codepen.io/myleschuahiock/pen/qZOydm**

This didn't work because your `questionText` variable is a string outside of the value of your subject. You need to do the `replace` then assign the value of `questionText` to your `input` with id "subject".

Here is working code:

```
 $("#subject").on('keyup', function phoneNumberC() {
    var phoneNumberRegex = /\d{10}/g;
    var questionText = document.getElementById('subject').value;
    var phoneNumberDetected = questionText.match(phoneNumberRegex);
    if (phoneNumberDetected != null) {
      phoneNumberDetected = String(phoneNumberDetected);
      var formattedPhone = "###-###-####";
      var formattedSubject = questionText.replace(phoneNumberDetected, formattedPhone);
      $("#subject").val(formattedSubject);
    }
  });
```

Comment: also, `document.getElementById('subject').value` can be shortened to `$("#subject")` ... or even ... you could specify `this` in the function call then reference `this.value`

Comment: Thank you very much!! This worked perfectly. And yes, I'm always guilty of not using `this.value` but I do this when polishing the code later.

Answer (score -2):

```js
function formatUSPhoneNumber(number) {

    var x = 0, groups = [], len, num;


    /* Force string conversion */
    num = number+'';


    /* Remove non numeric characters */
    num = num.replace(/\D/g,'');


    if(num.length !== 10){
        throw new Error('The argument passed needs to contain 10 digits.')
        return;
    }

    len = num.length;

    num = num.split('').reverse();

    while( x < len/3){
       groups[x] = num.splice(-3,3).reverse().join('');
       x++;
    }

    if( groups.length > 3 ){
       groups[2] = groups[2].concat( groups.splice( 3 - groups.length, 1 ) );
    }   

    return groups.join('-');
}
console.log(formatUSPhoneNumber("0545555555"))
```

Comment: This is more than what I need, I want to mask the phone number while typing in a textarea that has other text than the phone number itself.

Comment: Down vote because OP is asking to Mask the phone number, not convert it. Read before writing ;)